# DefaultIfEmpty().Max() still throws 'Sequence contains no elements.'

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

After I updated my project to dotnet core 3.0RC1 (might be in preview9 as well) my code that used to work

```
var value = context.Products.Where(t => t.CategoryId == catId).Select(t => t.Version).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

started throwing 
`System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`. The table in question is empty.

If I add `ToList()` so it looks like this `DeafultIfEmpty().ToList().Max()`, it starts to work again. Could not find any information about a breaking change. When I run

```
var expectedZero = new List<int>().DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

it works fine. That made me think maybe something wrong with EF Core. Then I created test in xUnit with exactly the same setup but there tests are passing (table is empty as well, uses InMemoryDatabase instead of live SQL Server instance).

I am truly puzzled. 
Relevant stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.
   at int lambda_method(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, int[], ResultCoordinator)
   at bool Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor+QueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at TSource System.Linq.Enumerable.Single<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
   at TResult Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
   at TResult Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
   at TSource System.Linq.Queryable.Max<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source)
   at ... (my method that run the code)
```

**Edit**

Product class:

```
   [Table("tmpExtProduct", Schema = "ext")]
    public partial class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Version { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Ext.Category))]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }        

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Ext.Category.Products))]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

**2nd edit**
Sql produced by ef core

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT MAX([t0].[Version])
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS [empty]
) AS [empty]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p].[Version], [p].[CategoryId], [p].[ImportDate], [p].[Description]
    FROM [ext].[tmpExtProduct] AS [p]
    WHERE (([p].[CategoryId] = @__categoryId_0) AND @__categoryId_0 IS NOT NULL)
) AS [t0] ON 1 = 1',N'@__categoryId_0 int',@__categoryId_0=5
```

Comment: Could you show us the Product class code? Specifically the property `Version`?

Comment: As requested, but Version is just an int (but also primary key). Still, there was no problem before. Now inspecting the result of `.DefaultIfEmpty()` returns `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<int>` with Results View containing `IEnumerable` with 1 item = 0 of type int.

Comment: OK was just double-checking it wasn't nullable. I guess my next request would be to see the SQL being generated by EF core, as that may have some additional clues. Otherwise I would suggest opening an [issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues) and see if you can find a resolution there. I can see that [InMemory support for default if empty was only added this last month](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/17484) so it's possible that could factor in here

Comment: Posted, but I do not see anything out of ordinary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I opened the [issue in EF Core repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17988) and got an answer. Apparently this is current behaviour, that may change later.

The suggestion is to use the following approach

```
var valueFail = context.Products.Where(t => t.CategoryId == catId)
                .GroupBy(e => 1)
                .Select(t => t.Max(e => e.Version))
                .ToList()[0];
```

This is better than my workaround `DeafultIfEmpty().ToList().Max()` as it will do all the work server-side, while my solution will calculate Max() on the client.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround might be using `OrderBy` and `FirstOrDefault` combination

```
var value = context.Products
    .Where(t => t.CategoryId == catId)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Version)
    .Select(t => t.Version)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I usually use this method and rarely use `Max()`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Sweet and simple

Answer (score 0):

By the [mikeyy's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58091493/6859121), an exception will still be throwed, but this exception message becomes to "Nullable object must have a value.". Because returns is null when sequence is empty, but null cannot be assigned to a value type `int`.

The correct thing to do is to cast the target value type to `Nullable<>`, which will return null instead of throw "Sequence contains no elements." or "Nullable object must have a value." exception when the sequence is empty.

```
var value = context.Products
    .Where(t => t.CategoryId == catId)
    .Select(t => (int?)t.Version)
    .Max();
```

Now, the type of variable `value` is `Nullable<int>`, remember to check it's null or not.